# JS function not fired in Django dropdown onchange event

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I've question, I've JS function which is used in Django project(downloaded from internet)
, so in template.html I've `<select class="select_filter" onchange="myFunc(this.value);"></select>`, also this function is declareted in this template.html

```
   <script>
    function myFunc(val)
    {
      console.log(val);
    }
    </script>
```

but in DevConsole in browser I got `Uncaught ReferenceError: myFuncis not defined`

P.S Jquery was enabled in page-source (checked from Ctrl+U)

Can anyone please guide and help with my problem?

Answer (score 0):

So, problem solved...
problem was in JS function visibility for it's using, just ,oved function to another place and all is worked fine!